# JavascriptExecutor Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I can not perform the function `doFilterOffer()` on the page , it 's the following error `missing ; before statement` , what's wrong with this syntax below?

```
    if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {

        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("Function doFilterOffer();", "click");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `Function` word:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("doFilterOffer();", "click");
```